# How to properly modify 2 lines of another plugins

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am coding some permalinks rewrite for WooCommerce awesome plugin.
Everything is well packed in a plugin and work well... except for one thing.

WooCommerce use get_term_link() to display HTML link in default template. A lot of custom templates use it too. If I want to display the good link on my website, I must change one line of code in woocommerce plugin. This is dirty, since basic user would not do it. Since I want to list it on Wordpress plugin repertory, I would like some help here...

What I need to do :

Open woocommerce.php and replace line 767 :

```
OLD 
$product_category_slug  = empty( $permalinks['category_base'] ) ? _x( 'product-category', 'slug', 'woocommerce' ) : $permalinks['category_base'];

NEW
$product_category_slug  = '';
```

Very easy to do by editing the file, but it is dirty. It is non user friendly, and it depends a lot of woocommerce next version... So my question here: how can I do it from my own plugin, without asking people to open their woocommerce plugin with Notepad++... Is there any way ?

I hope you understand my need and could provide me with an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I already did same thing in Past.

Please Don't Modify `WooCommerce Core files`, Because it will be gone in your next upgrade.

Use this [Custom Permlink](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) Plugin, You will get Better Options there,

Comment: Hi @phpdeveloper and thank you for your prompt answer. We both agree : modyfing plugin source is bad. I wrote my own plugin to do what I wanted. My problem is : I do not find any way of changing link that are generated by WooCommerce plugin without editing this link. Any advice here ?

Comment: What i understood is, You want to remove "Category-Base"... Have you try to install it -- http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Comment: thank you. This plugin is very usefull for me to understand how to add 301 redirect rules. Only one thing I need to fix: is there any way to change the category links generated by woocommerce : http://dev.emp1.fr/accessoires/sacoche-en-neoprene-avec-poignee-pour-netbook-de-7-a-10-pouces/ (all categories link actually contain "category-produit", I want to remove it). Thank

Comment: Yes, It is possible -
Please Go to "Settings" -> "Permalinks" -> You will find certain options there, Change "Product category base" with your custom name:

Btw, If i helped you through then please upvote/accept answer